# Cannot Navigate in Neo4j with Browser

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j to model my nlp research and so far I can insert data to server with python. However, I cannot "browse" it using the browser http connection. I log in to "localhost:7474/browser" and the interface is there, but no button render results (executing a query just cleans the query and thats it).

There's a message in the left panel "Browser Sync is disabled due to Neo4j server configuration. Raise the issue with your administrator." but so far I could not find out how to solve this (not even en Neo4j website).

Weird is that using it on Windows through installer went ok, but by running it standalone on linux (kubuntu 18) its not working (connection is up and running!)

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: don't look t `Browser Sync`, it's not the problem. Can you tale a screenshot with the `Database Information` pannel opened ? Same with a query execution ?

Comment: are you using the version 3.4.8 and do you have disabled the auth of neo4j ?